# interpolate between first and last valid values then fill Nan values by zeros for dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, fillna

I have csv file like the below table:

| depth | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| depth | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| 1000 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1001 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1002 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1003 | Nan | 10 | Nan |
| 1004 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1005 | Nan | Nan | 10 |
| 1006 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1007 | 10 | Nan | Nan |
| 1008 | 11 | Nan | Nan |
| 1009 | 12 | Nan | Nan |
| 1010 | 13 | Nan | Nan |
| 1011 | 14 | Nan | 15 |
| 1012 | 15 | 20 | Nan |
| 1013 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1014 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1015 | 18 | Nan | Nan |
| 1016 | 19 | Nan | Nan |
| 1017 | 20 | Nan | Nan |
| 1018 | 21 | Nan | 20 |
| 1019 | 22 | Nan | Nan |
| 1020 | 23 | Nan | Nan |
| 1021 | 24 | 25 | Nan |
| 1022 | 25 | Nan | Nan |
| 1023 | 26 | Nan | Nan |
| 1024 | 27 | Nan | 25 |
| 1025 | 28 | 15 | Nan |
| 1026 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1027 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 1028 | Nan | Nan | Nan |

I want interpolate between first and last valid values then fill Nan values by zeros
the result should be like that

| depth | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1002 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1003 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 1004 | 0 | 11.11111111 | 0 |
| 1005 | 0 | 12.22222222 | 10 |
| 1006 | 0 | 13.33333333 | 10.83333333 |
| 1007 | 10 | 14.44444444 | 11.66666667 |
| 1008 | 11 | 15.55555556 | 12.5 |
| 1009 | 12 | 16.66666667 | 13.33333333 |
| 1010 | 13 | 17.77777778 | 14.16666667 |
| 1011 | 14 | 18.88888889 | 15 |
| 1012 | 15 | 20 | 15.71428571 |
| 1013 | 16 | 20.55555556 | 16.42857143 |
| 1014 | 17 | 21.11111111 | 17.14285714 |
| 1015 | 18 | 21.66666667 | 17.85714286 |
| 1016 | 19 | 22.22222222 | 18.57142857 |
| 1017 | 20 | 22.77777778 | 19.28571429 |
| 1018 | 21 | 23.33333333 | 20 |
| 1019 | 22 | 23.88888889 | 20.83333333 |
| 1020 | 23 | 24.44444444 | 21.66666667 |
| 1021 | 24 | 25 | 22.5 |
| 1022 | 25 | 22.5 | 23.33333333 |
| 1023 | 26 | 20 | 24.16666667 |
| 1024 | 27 | 17.5 | 25 |
| 1025 | 28 | 15 | 25 |
| 1026 | 28 | 0 | 0 |
| 1027 | 28 | 0 | 0 |
| 1028 | 28 | 0 | 0 |

I have tried the below code but it does not give the correct result

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mohamed\OneDrive\Desktop\test_interpolate.csv")
df = df.interpolate()
df = df.fillna(0)
print (df)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\mohamed\OneDrive\Desktop\result.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the interpolation to the inner NaN using `limit_area='inside'` (this is well covered in the documentation of [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)):

```
df = df.interpolate(limit_area='inside').fillna(0)
```

output:

```
    depth    x1         x2         x3
0    1000   0.0   0.000000   0.000000
1    1001   0.0   0.000000   0.000000
2    1002   0.0   0.000000   0.000000
3    1003   0.0  10.000000   0.000000
4    1004   0.0  11.111111   0.000000
5    1005   0.0  12.222222  10.000000
6    1006   0.0  13.333333  10.833333
7    1007  10.0  14.444444  11.666667
8    1008  11.0  15.555556  12.500000
9    1009  12.0  16.666667  13.333333
10   1010  13.0  17.777778  14.166667
11   1011  14.0  18.888889  15.000000
12   1012  15.0  20.000000  15.714286
13   1013  16.0  20.555556  16.428571
14   1014  17.0  21.111111  17.142857
15   1015  18.0  21.666667  17.857143
16   1016  19.0  22.222222  18.571429
17   1017  20.0  22.777778  19.285714
18   1018  21.0  23.333333  20.000000
19   1019  22.0  23.888889  20.833333
20   1020  23.0  24.444444  21.666667
21   1021  24.0  25.000000  22.500000
22   1022  25.0  22.500000  23.333333
23   1023  26.0  20.000000  24.166667
24   1024  27.0  17.500000  25.000000
25   1025  28.0  15.000000   0.000000
26   1026   0.0   0.000000   0.000000
27   1027   0.0   0.000000   0.000000
28   1028   0.0   0.000000   0.000000
```