# pandas extrapolation of polynomial

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Interpolating is easy in pandas using `df.interpolate()`
is there a method in pandas that with the same elegance do something like extrapolate. I know my extrapolation is fitted to a second degree polynom.

Comment: You may have to use `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline` which has an `ext` option.

Comment: Related: [Extrapolate values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe), but a simpler case that was able to be solved by another method.

Comment: There is now an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35959909/2087463) to that question with specifics on the polynomial extrapolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"With the same elegance" is a somewhat tall order but this can be done. As far as I'm aware you'll need to compute the extrapolated values manually. Note it is very unlikely these values will be very meaningful unless the data you are operating on actually obey a law of the form of the interpolant.

For example, since you requested a second degree polynomial fit:

```
import numpy as np
t = df["time"]
dat = df["data"]
p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(t,data,2))
```

Now p(t) is the value of the best-fit polynomial at time t.

Answer (score 0):

## Extrapolation

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe/35959909#35959909) for how to [extrapolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation) the values of each column of a `DataFrame` with a [3<sup>rd</sup> order polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).  A [different order (e.g. 2<sup>nd</sup> order) polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Names_of_polynomials_by_degree) may easily be used by altering `func()`.

> Snippet from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe/35959909#35959909)
>
> ```py
> # Function to curve fit to the data
> def func(x, a, b, c, d):
>     return a * (x ** 3) + b * (x ** 2) + c * x + d
>
> # Initial parameter guess, just to kick off the optimization
> guess = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
>
> # Create copy of data to remove NaNs for curve fitting
> fit_df = df.dropna()
>
> # Place to store function parameters for each column
> col_params = {}
>
> # Curve fit each column
> for col in fit_df.columns:
>     # Get x & y
>     x = fit_df.index.astype(float).values
>     y = fit_df[col].values
>     # Curve fit column and get curve parameters
>     params = curve_fit(func, x, y, guess)
>     # Store optimized parameters
>     col_params[col] = params[0]
>
> # Extrapolate each column
> for col in df.columns:
>     # Get the index values for NaNs in the column
>     x = df[pd.isnull(df[col])].index.astype(float).values
>     # Extrapolate those points with the fitted function
>     df[col][x] = func(x, *col_params[col])
> ```