# Extrapolate Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, extrapolation

It is easy to interpolate values in a `Pandas.DataFrame` using `Series.interpolate`, how can extrapolation be done?

For example, given a DataFrame as shown, how can we extrapolate it 14 more months to 2014-12-31? Linear extrapolation is fine.

```
X1 = range(10)
X2 = map(lambda x: x**2, X1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': X1, 'x2': X2},  index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10,freq='M'))
```

I am thinking that a new DataFrame must first be created, with the DateTimeIndex starting from 2013-11-31 and extending for 14 more `M` periods. Beyond that I'm stuck.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with replacing `10` by `24` ?

Comment: @tmoreau `df` may be read from a .CSV, so we dont have access to the `periods` parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extrapolate values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 19):

### Extrapolating a `DataFrame` with a `DatetimeIndex` index

This can be done with two steps:

1. Extend the [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)
2. Extrapolate the data

### Extend the Index

Overwrite `df` with a new `DataFrame` where the data is [resampled](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) onto a new *extended* index based on original [index's start, period and frequency](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html). This allows the original `df` to come from anywhere, as in the `csv` example case. With this the columns get conveniently [filled with NaNs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=NaN)!

```py
# Fake DataFrame for example (could come from anywhere)
X1 = range(10)
X2 = map(lambda x: x**2, X1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': X1, 'x2': X2},  index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10,freq='M'))

# Number of months to extend
extend = 5

# Extrapolate the index first based on original index
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=df,
    index=pd.date_range(
        start=df.index[0],
        periods=len(df.index) + extend,
        freq=df.index.freq
    )
)

# Display
print df
```

---

```
    x1  x2
2013-01-31   0   0
2013-02-28   1   1
2013-03-31   2   4
2013-04-30   3   9
2013-05-31   4  16
2013-06-30   5  25
2013-07-31   6  36
2013-08-31   7  49
2013-09-30   8  64
2013-10-31   9  81
2013-11-30 NaN NaN
2013-12-31 NaN NaN
2014-01-31 NaN NaN
2014-02-28 NaN NaN
2014-03-31 NaN NaN
```

### Extrapolate the data

Most extrapolators will require the inputs to be numeric instead of dates. This can be done with

```py
# Temporarily remove dates and make index numeric
di = df.index
df = df.reset_index().drop('index', 1)
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe/35959909#35959909) for how to extrapolate the values of each column of a `DataFrame` with a [3<sup>rd</sup> order polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

> Snippet from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe/35959909#35959909)
>
> ```py
> # Curve fit each column
> for col in fit_df.columns:
>     # Get x & y
>     x = fit_df.index.astype(float).values
>     y = fit_df[col].values
>     # Curve fit column and get curve parameters
>     params = curve_fit(func, x, y, guess)
>     # Store optimized parameters
>     col_params[col] = params[0]
>
> # Extrapolate each column
> for col in df.columns:
>     # Get the index values for NaNs in the column
>     x = df[pd.isnull(df[col])].index.astype(float).values
>     # Extrapolate those points with the fitted function
>     df[col][x] = func(x, *col_params[col])
> ```

Once the columns are extrapolated, put the dates back

```py
# Put date index back
df.index = di

# Display
print df
```

---

```
x1   x2
2013-01-31   0    0
2013-02-28   1    1
2013-03-31   2    4
2013-04-30   3    9
2013-05-31   4   16
2013-06-30   5   25
2013-07-31   6   36
2013-08-31   7   49
2013-09-30   8   64
2013-10-31   9   81
2013-11-30  10  100
2013-12-31  11  121
2014-01-31  12  144
2014-02-28  13  169
2014-03-31  14  196
```

Comment: I only have one question.. I followed your steps and everything seemed to work out just fine, except I get a warning from scipy: `OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)` Do you know why that could be the case?