# Interpolating and extrapolating panel data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, extrapolation

I have panel data in a dataframe:

```
id    pop2010    pop2015
1001     1000       1300
1002      500        650
...
```

I want to linearly interpolate the data for each year between 2010 and 2015, and then create a new column for `pop2016` and linearly extrapolate for this year. How can I do this?

I can reshape to 'long' data (using `pd.wide_to_long()`), and then use `df.interpolate()` to do the interpolation. But if I create a column for `pop2016` and then reshape and interpolate, it interpolates using values from different municipalities (indexed by `id`), which I don't want. So I need to interpolate first, and then reshape back to wide format, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe) don't seem very helpful, since they don't address panel data.

Comment: We may need to see more about the structure of the dataframe you have, since based on the excerpt you included, I don't see why `df.interpolate()` with the appropriate `axis` parameter wouldn't work.

Comment: Okay, so using `interpolate(axis=1)` with wide data works for interpolation, although it doesn't like the `id` column being there. It extrapolates using the 'nearest' method, i.e. copying over the 2015 value.