# pandas.interpolate (method = 'linear') just copies values on first and last point

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a bit new to `pandas.interpolate`.

I have a pandas dataframe indexed by years from 2011 from 2017. I sometimes have missing values so I used interpolate with `method='linear'` and `limit_direction='both'` to fill the gaps.

The screenshot below features the original dataframe (top) and the interpolation result (bottom).

When a missing value is located between non-missing values, everything works fine: on the example below, a brand new value is generated in 2016.

But when the NAs are at the beginning or at the end of the series, I am not satisfied by the result because it turns out that it is just a mere copy of the next non-missing values: on the example below, you can see that 2011 and 2012 were given the same value as 2013.

[image]

Then, I tried to use `method='polynomial'` with `order=2` to get a "smoother" interpolation, but I got the following error:

```
ValueError: number of derivatives at boundaries.
```

Can someone explain to me why I'm doing it wrong and which method I could use to get a nice interpolation, including for the first and the last value?

Comment: On the edge you have _extra_polation.

Comment: This seems to be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I thought the method interpolate() could make *both* interpolation and extrapolation. I see that it's a bit more complicated than that. I'll give it a go.