# pandas.interpolate doesn't give wanted result

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, interpolation

i'm trying to fill the empty y field in my dataset[from 12 to 16]
, here is the original data vizualisation 
[image]

I have NaN values at the end, here is my code

```
df=df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2, limit_direction ='both')
```

I have tried many methods (‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘spline’, ‘barycentric'), all of them gave the following result

[image]

As you see, from 12 to 14 the result is not the sinusoidal extension of my data, it just clone the first elements.

Comment: Can you share your `df` or how you generated it?

Comment: have you tried with a higher ```order``` (3 or 4) and/or ```limit_direction='forward'```?

Comment: @DerekO I just generate the x data from 12 to 15 with x_extend=np.arange(start=np.max(x), stop=15, step=x_step) , step is the mean step of given dataset. then i concatenate the main dataset, with the generated one

Comment: @99_m4n yes I did, it gave the same result.

Comment: What about the given dataset? Can you provide a sample of it?

Comment: @DerekO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cBCqskU_Co-tc5EP3_9zMmHL5B9YGxmh/view?usp=sharing here is a link of the original one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extrapolate values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @DerekO i tried what they did, the result wasn't there

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe), when you want to extrapolate data which is infer how the data behaves outside of the scope of interpolation, you need to rely on some more powerful [interpolation functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) from the scipy library  or write an interpolation function on your own.

Although this may be a bit beyond what you were asking, I think your data is clearly a periodic function so polynomial functions or splines will continue unbounded past the endpoint of your original data set. Instead, [trigonometric interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation#math_4) might extrapolate better due to its periodic behavior, and you can simplify the computational complexity by interpolating to equidistant points in your data set (e.g. don't fit a trigonometric function to all 500 points)

Edit: you can also use trigonometric least squares which is just least squares but with basis functions `[1, cos(ax), sin(bx)]`. I created an app that computes trigonometric least squares using a grid search to determine a,b. Feel free to repurpose the [TrigPolynomial class](https://github.com/merillium/trig_least_squares/blob/master/venv/trig_polynomials.py#L10-L99) I wrote in that app.