# Pandas interpolate NaN of shifted time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

When I shift my time series data, I get some NaNs in the dataframe. The only interpolation method that can replace these NaNs with numbers is `'linear'`. The NaN are replaced by the same number, which isn't preferable.

Is there some way to instead use a different method like `'cubic'` or `'quadratic'`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# original data
df = pd.DataFrame()
np.random.seed(0)

days = pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2015-01-10', freq='1D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'col1': np.random.randn(len(days))})
df = df.set_index('Date')

# add lags
df['lag1'] = df['col1'].shift(1)
df['lag3'] = df['col1'].shift(3)

print(df)

def interp(dfObj):
    if dfObj.isna().sum()>0:
        dfObj0 = dfObj.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='both')
        return dfObj0
    else:
        return dfObj

df['lag1'] = interp(df['lag1'])
df['lag3'] = interp(df['lag3'])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the fact that the null values are at the beginning of the data frame, and as such the interpolation has no values to interpolate between. In this case, you need to perform *extrapolation*, for which pandas does not have a built in method. See this thread for more details.

[Extrapolate Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491628/extrapolate-values-in-pandas-dataframe)