# How to interpolate the first and the last values using pandas.DataFrame.interpolate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I know that this question has been asked before, but the suggested solutions that I found to not work for me. Maybe I am trying to do something that is simply not possible, but let me explain.

I have a time-series `data` that has some values of `0`. I would like to interpolate the zeros in `data` using `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [0, -1.31527, -2.25448, -0.965348, -1.11168, -0.0506046, -0.605522,
        2.01337, 0, 0, 2.41931, 0.821425, 0.402411, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data) # Data to pandas dataframe
df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan, inplace=True) # Replace 0 by nan
ip = df.interpolate(method="nearest", order=3, limit=None,
                    limit_direction=None)
print(ip)
```

The result of `print(ip)`:

```
           0
0        NaN
1  -1.315270
2  -2.254480
3  -0.965348
4  -1.111680
5  -0.050605
6  -0.605522
7   2.013370
8   2.013370
9   2.419310
10  2.419310
11  0.821425
12  0.402411
13       NaN
```

**The problem:** Pandas does not interpolate the first and last value of `data`, but leaves them as zeros. I tried all options of `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate` out forward and back, but it does not seem to work interpolating the first and last zero of `data`. Is this simply impossible via Pandas or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need further information about the "shape" of the values. Furthermore, there is no actual function of pandas that implements it quickly. Here is a more sophisticated answer of a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959909/16872314

Comment: what you want is an extrapolation, what would be the explicit expected output?

Comment: Thanks. I just read throuth the link provided by Marcello Zago. There was a mistake in my script, since the ```method="nearest"``` should be ```method="polynomial```. The original time-series is much longer than my example provided here. To answer your question: my aim is to not just apply the cubic polynomial for interpolation, but for extrapolation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an **extrapolation**, you need to decide on how to do this.

You can `ffill`/`bfill`:

```
ip = (df.interpolate(method="nearest", order=3, limit=None,
                     limit_direction='both')
        .ffill().bfill()
     )
```

Output:

```
           0
0  -1.315270
1  -1.315270
2  -2.254480
3  -0.965348
4  -1.111680
5  -0.050605
6  -0.605522
7   2.013370
8   2.013370
9   2.419310
10  2.419310
11  0.821425
12  0.402411
13  0.402411
```

[image]

Or use a spline:

```
ip = (df.interpolate(method="nearest", order=3, limit=None,
                     limit_direction=None)
        .fillna(
      df.interpolate(method="spline", order=3, limit=None,
                     limit_direction='both')
        )
     )
```

Output:

```
           0
0  -0.585237
1  -1.315270
2  -2.254480
3  -0.965348
4  -1.111680
5  -0.050605
6  -0.605522
7   2.013370
8   2.013370
9   2.419310
10  2.419310
11  0.821425
12  0.402411
13 -1.951716
```

Output:

[image]